# If a condition is true how to extract specific rows addressing that condition from a csv file as print result

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, text-mining

If I have 2 conditions: 1. a document is health relate 2. a document is not health-related
and my document satisfies one of the above-mentioned conditions. As an output, it must pull out data from a CSV file from rows associated with this condition say row 1, 5, and 8, and print it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/csv')

print(df.iloc[1, 5, 8])
```

Comment: This manually prints rows 1,5,8, but they want to find rows matching health condition (although the health condition is not explained clearly)